# Can I restore overwritten AWS Lambda function or get some previous deployed function changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm very new in using Lambda service. I upload new zip to my function, and it overwrite the whole function. Is there a way to restore previous work of function or some history of function deployment. I don't have any published versions or so... :(